# Determine which Language aspx file is using

Tags: c#

Is it possible to determine which language the asp file is using?

What I mean by language, I mean the following:

```
Language=VB
```

Is there a way, in `C#`, to determine which language the `aspx` file is using? Whether it be `VB` or `C#`.

Comment: Are you looking to check this during runtime of the app itself (which I suspect), or by parsing the source code from an external tool?

Comment: @squillman: Yes, during the runtime itself.

Comment: I'm curious why you need to know this, and I'm not sure if it's even possible. At runtime the CLR is simply JITing and execuitng IL.

Comment: @DanWilson: There is an editor that I work with where, lets call them "letters", are sent out to user describing Doctor Visits. Within this code, html along with some programming, whether it be C# or VB, is implemented to create these letters. Within the editor, you are able to call scripts to do like coversheets and so forth. I was tasked to figure out a way, if possible, to determine which language the program is running in. Reason being, it would be time consuming to go to each letter and change the file name to the appropriate one (C#/VB was implemented to apply new info. )

Comment: @DanWilson: I also figured it doesnt seem likely there is a way to do it. Thanks for you help

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). Why do you need to “go to each letter and change the file name”? Fix your code so you don't have to do that, don't mess around with “which language the asp file is using”.

Comment: I still fail to see why it matters. The language is used only at compile time to generate the supporting code in the `.dll` file. The `.aspx` file is language agnostic, it will get compiled at run time and only needs the supporting code behind to also exist in the module. It does not care if that was compiled in c# or vb.net.

Comment: @DourHighArch I need to go to each letter because each language can be programmed in either VB or C# (dont ask my why they are programmed either or. It was like that before my time). However, it cant be done and I will  look into other approaches

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input. It is greatly appreciated